# Would it be well-received to ask for the LaTeX source of a textbook?

Tags: publications, books, health, latex, reading

My screen reader has a hard time with PDF documents. As I delve into more niche textbooks, I increasingly find them only in print/PDF rather than [EPUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB).

This makes it difficult to learn when the screen reader's OCR is not good. Would it be fruitful to ask people for LaTeX versions of their textbooks or would this be poorly received? I write LaTeX content fairly often, so I think this should be easily comprehensible if I listen to it in bulk.

The issue may also be related to using scihub/libgen, which may have worse prints of the books/papers (although I've seen this in my purchased PDFs as well).

Comment: I don't know your personal circumstances, but depending what they are, it's possible your university has someone whose job is to solve problems like this for you.

Comment: Can't you get a better screen reader?

Comment: If you are looking at scientific papers on arxiv.org the standard option is downloading a pdf but you can select getting the raw tex file as well. For general pdf there is also pdf to latex software but I have no experience in how good it is.

Comment: I am on the whole enthusiastic for the desire for "source-available" documents. But it seems like you would be happy with an epub. Have you considered asking for that instead?

Comment: @preferred_anon Why are you so enthusiastic? It facilitates copy-pasting. What is so good about that?

Comment: @yarchik Essentially, for the same reason the OP wants the source. I think people have a right to read and use the document the way they see fit. That includes increasing print size, changing colour and font, converting to other formats, reading aloud, correcting typos, adding marginal notes, copying text for legitimate purposes (i.e. with attribution), learning the typesetting language... The list goes on. Copy-pasting (with attribution, where appropriate) is a good thing.

Comment: @preferred_anon Some points are good, any pdf document supports adjustment of the visual presentation, but learning the typesetting from a published book is a bit ridiculous.

Comment: @NickS [Better Screen Reader for math?](https://www.westernu.edu/mediafiles/cdihp/math-aids.pdf) OP, which niche of the arcana are you studying?

Comment: I published several books written using latex. In all cases, I do not even have a TeX file of a final version, it is with the publisher. And my last TeX file differs substantially from the final version.

Comment: @NickS - Not really? I have tried many and all seem to run into problems, either with reading PDFs with multiple lines or textbooks (this post was spurred by me trying to read a PDF where each screen reader spent ~3 minutes just saying "dot dot dot ..." in what seems to be an empty page)

Comment: @user121330 - math

Comment: PDF is designed initially for print, so it doesn't (by default) contain semantic information like "this is a header": it's just larger text. That kind of stuff *can* be added to a PDF, but it's often missing. Any complex formatting (pull quotes, sidebar boxes, equations, diagrams) can often be stored in a manner which will very much confuse screen readers and other assistive software.

Comment: Isn't it possibly to compile LaTeX to EPUB instead of PDF? Or to some format easily converted to EPUB? If so, you could ask for that instead.

Comment: Niche textbooks at the university level may be self-published by the university, and the author and who is helping him may not be aware of the accessibility requirements.

Comment: @PabloH *Nothing* is easily converted to EPUB.  I know because I'm struggling with that very problem. Also note that, since many EPUB readers do not support MathML, equations in EPUB are as likely to be images as in PDF.

Answer (score 35):

Slight frame challenge: Instead of just asking for a LaTeX source, which might indeed come across very strange, tell the author what you told us: Your screen reader is struggling with the PDF, and you're looking for a better way, for example the source. The author might be more likely to give you the source if they understand your reason, or maybe they know how to get an epub or other format from the publisher (or they might even go through the trouble of compiling the source into an epub).

Comment: I would say this is a more useful answer to the OP than the one by @DCTLib, but the points about why an author might not even have the source or be allowed to give it away are good ones.
Asking the publisher might be a better way to go.

Comment: Would I need to have bought the textbook for this? I generally use scihub/libgen for exploratory reading

Answer (score 20):

It is certainly uncommon to ask for LaTeX sources of textbooks, and while some authors may provide them for you, it is fair to expect that this will rarely work out, for a variety of reasons.

1. The author of the text book may suspect that you need the LaTeX code for another reason, e.g., for including a part in a thesis document or so.
2. The copyright of textbooks often/normally lie with the publishers, who may not like it if an author gives out the *source* for something they legally own.
3. LaTeX code that you did not write yourself is rarely easy to read. It's often full of macros for injecting key words, equation symbols, and the like.
4. In the disciplines that don't use equations a lot, it's quite likely that only the publisher has the LaTeX code (or the source file for any other software they may have used instead) for a book, because the author actually wrote it in a different format and then professionals formatted the whole thing.

Because of reasons 1 and 2, I would find such a request very strange as an author, but probably not strange enough to try to remember your name when receiving your e-mail.

Comment: For point 4, depending on the publisher the book might be more likely to have been formatted in some other software like InDesign.

Comment: Re point 4 - I would say it's more likely that the author used LaTeX and the publisher converted, than the other way round, at least in physics

Comment: All points are quite valid, especially point 3. Much better to ask for ePub.

Comment: @Anyon Thanks, I've added that possibility to the answer.

Comment: (*[keywords](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/keyword#Noun)*?)

Comment: @yarchik: I wouldn’t suggest *just* asking for an epub, since if one doesn’t already exist, preparing one is a fair bit of work, so most authors are likely to say no.  I’d rather suggest asking for “an epub if you have one, or the source so I can make an epub myself for personal use”.

Answer (score 1):

### There is no guarantee that the source is in LaTeX

LaTeX is a pain to write, but we all love its output. There are several tools that generate output that looks like LaTeX's from documents that weren't written in it. For example, I am an enjoyer of [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/). I write all of my work in Markdown, but Pandoc makes it look like I wrote LaTeX. Similarly, I know of people who use [LyX](https://www.lyx.org/) which is not LaTeX but generates output indistinguishable from it.

I do not know how common such non-LaTeX approaches are, but in such cases, you're doomed.

Comment: You don't need to use the **largest possible heading font** to preface your barely-two-paragraph answer.

Comment: @user1271772 Fair point. I've reduced it.

Comment: Thanks, I'd still recommend just using bold font in this case (or maybe ### or #### if you really want it to be bigger), but your newer version is already significantly looking significantly better in my opinion.